# Add/remove (in)active class from Bootstrap Collapse plugin's headings

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wrestling a bit with the collapse JS from bootstrap. On my website I want to use the collapse to display some content. I want, whenever the user clicks on the heading to apply the class "active" to it. It already starts out with the class "inactive". So from inactive it goes to active when you click on it. On the other hand, it should when you re-click the same heading also change back to inactive. Which is currently not what it does now.

Here is the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Malachute/tZeT8/1/  Don't mind the collapse not working, that's working on my end and bad copied into JSfiddle.

Comment: Any luck using the code below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this. Sorry, it's not pretty:

```
$(function(){
var sidebar = $('.accordion-heading');  // cache sidebar to a variable for performance

sidebar.delegate('.accordion-toggle','click',function(){ 
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('inactive');
 }else{
  sidebar.find('.active').addClass('inactive');          
  sidebar.find('.active').removeClass('active');   
  $(this).removeClass('inactive');
  $(this).addClass('active');
 }
});
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ckaufman/tZeT8/2/